# Windows Phone 7 Splash Screen Minimum Time

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, splash-screen

I have a splash screen in my Silverlight WP7 app but my app loads so quick that my splash screen only shows up for a brief moment.

Is there a way to force my splash screen to be shown for at least two seconds?

Comment: You'd have to display it yourself, probably with using the Loaded event of the page. But in general, if your app loads so quickly, don't even bother with the splash screen. Not sure about your requirements, but as the user, I don't care at all about your company - I don't want to see a splash screen for no reason.

Comment: hehe "as the user, I don't care at all about your company" good point, I think i'm gonna leave it out than.

Answer (score 9):

I know am posting the answer really really late.. I am posting it so that someone else can use it.. The solution is very simple..

```
using System.Threading;
namespace Trial
 {
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
      {
         // Constructor
         public MainPage()
           {
              InitializeComponent();
              Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
      }
 }
```

Here LoginPage is the first page that is loaded right after my splash screen. so before InitializeComponent() is called am just putting this particular thread for sleep for 3 secs so that my spalsh screen is displayed a little longer.

Hope it helps someone in the future

Comment: HI Apoorva, I have tried your above code but i dont know what is LoginListener,CacheManager  and DataManager in your code.I used your code but it gave me errors.so how to solve those error?

Comment: np.. the other lines were a part of my code.. sorry for confusing you.

Comment: Its ok. Actually I did the same thing using developing a usercontrol for splash screen and BackgroundWorker. it was very complex code.But as u updated your code, it helps me a lot and will save my time to do the same thing in other apps. Thanks again...

Comment: @Apoorva i think it would be better to put sleep after init. otherwise it will give a flicker going to main page from splash.

Comment: ThnQ! @Deekey.. Am glad it helped few more WP enthusiasts

Answer (score 5):

you could calculate something really expensive, or Thread.Sleep in your startup code.

why you'd want to waste the user's time to show a splash screen any longer than you need to is not obvoius to me, though.